# How to test React component return by other React component's method

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

Here is the sample code, In the following code `<MyComponent />` has method called `getHeader`. I am trying to test `getHeader` method.

```
const Header = ({title})=> {
  return <Header> {title} </Header>
}

export class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  getHeader(title) {
    return <Header title={title} />
  }
  render() {
    return <div>{ this.getHeader()}</div>
  }
}
```

And Here is the test, I want to test `getHeader()` method

```
 const myComponent = shallow(<MyComponent />);
 const header = myComponent.instance().getHeader('hello');

 // the following code always fails. Any suggestion
 expect(shallow(header).instance()).to.be.instanceOf(Header);
```

Comment: I don't think you need to mount it again - 
`expect(header).to.be.instanceOf(Header)`
should work

Comment: Should `Header` be trying to render more `Headers` components?  Also, should `this.getHeader()` be passing a parameter?

Answer (score 1):

I did a lot of trial and error to figure this out. Here is what my code looks like, and it succeeds.

```
const component = shallow(<MyComponent {...props}/>);

let yourComponent = (component.instance() as MyComponent).getYourComponent(); 
expect(yourComponent).not.toBeNull();
expect(yourComponent.type).toEqual(YourComponent);
```

The key here is you have to do `yourComponent.type` to get the equality to the class you want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a better way, but this passes:

```
let header = new MyComponent().getHeader('test')

expect(header).to.deep.equal(<Header title="test" />)
```

Note: this doesn't rely on rendering the component at all, it is purely testing the getter.

I do question the value of this test and would advise you to test the expected rendering of the component for given inputs, rather than worrying about exactly which getters it's using to get there.  This will make refactoring easier in the long run. Something like:

```
let myComponent = shallow(<MyComponent />)

expect(myComponent.find(Header).exists()).to.be.true
expect(myComponent.find(Header).props()).to.deep.equal({ title: undefined })
```